# Has anyone made a "social button" for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, logo, icons

Something along the lines of these:

http://blog.lunarpages.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/socialbuttons.png
(image is broken)

I haven't seen one yet, but if one exists, that would be great.

Comment: What would it do?

Comment: You would use it so link to your stack overflow/super user/server fault profile on your website...that's what they are used for...

Comment: social buttons like those above are for sharing content, not linking to profile - have you ever clicked on one? ;-)

Comment: Steven: I've also seen them used to link to profile pages.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing this.  ask a question then see if someone on fb or twitter can answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a "social button" because of the connotation, I'd just call it an icon.  That being said, yes someone's made one:
[Stackoverflow Icon http://jeremy.am/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/stackoverflow_glossy_1.png](http://jeremy.am/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/stackoverflow_glossy_1.png)

Source: http://jeremy.am/wordpress-plugins/find-me-on/comment-page-2/#comment-106

Comment: This is just what I'm looking for, but that's now gone. Any idea where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

[Got flair?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)

<sub>NB: You'll also find this link in *your* profile...</sub>

Comment: That's not what I described. At all.

Comment: Really? I mean they are bits of web code for you to put places like...um...your website, and they...um...link to your Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: Yes, but they aren't buttons...they are flair. It's nitpicky, I know. But a social button is a small square button (usually no larger than 60x60) that simply links to your profile page. There is no text on the button other than the logo of the site being linked to.

Comment: @Thomas So this is like a social button, only much more useful?

Comment: Michael: More useful, yet. But if you are using other social buttons to link to your facebook, twitter, and linked in profiles, then flair really sticks out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to a user profile simply click the **got flair?** link on your user page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

We only do this on public betas.

for example on http://photos.stackexchange.com (currently in public beta)

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/help-us-grow-this-site1.png))</sub>

Comment: I'm looking for something to link TO a stack overflow profile with on my site.

Comment: @Thomas see my update