# I killed a question

Tags: support, moderator-abilities

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314638/why-does-windows-start-chkdsk-at-boot-time) was flagged for mod attention because it had been [moved to Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/163242/why-does-windows-start-chkdsk-at-boot-time) even though it was really a programming question.

So I try to edit it before reopening. That doesn't work. I figure it's because the question is still locked, so I go unlock it. Then I go ahead and reopen it. It still says "migrated to serverfault.com", so I hunt around and discover the "clear migration history" option. Great. So I click it and
[image]

Uh oh.

What did I do wrong? Is this a bug?

<sub>Should I even be reporting this publicly?</sub>

Comment: Well, I suppose the least that could be done is flag on SF to get it migrated back.

Comment: Dont' worry. It looks like someone is workin on ur problem.

Comment: The proper course is to blame another mod.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3314638/revisions) is still there. So you can finish your cleanup, for all the good it'll do...

Comment: I still have it open in another tab, since I was about to save it when the "Save Edits" button disabled itself. Yeah, it might not be worth the effort in the first place, but I do think it deserves a chance.

Comment: @mmyers: [what](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58127/when-i-visit-so-and-a-favorite-question-has-changed-i-get-sent-to-an-empty-page/58130#58130) [have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58148/has-anyone-made-a-social-button-for-stack-overflow) [you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58164/home-improvement-account-missing-from-associated-accounts-tab) [done??!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58178/career-crisis-going-from-technical-to-more-on-management-side)

Comment: @Shog9: [It's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58148/has-anyone-made-a-social-button-for-stack-overflow) [spreading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58142/how-did-a-special-character-tag-get-into-the-system)! Run while you still can!

Comment: This is why you shouldn't build websites on .NET!

Comment: You found a free lolcat... and you're complaining about it?

Comment: I just got a video .. it shows the questions alive and well (for now), looks like they're being held in some kind of a warehouse. The people behind it are demanding waffles, lots and lots of waffles .. and a pony to take them out of the country.

Comment: One down! Keep up the good work, @mmyers!

Comment: now it's 404 at SF and oops at SO...

Answer (score 4):

I think we'll be making that (remove migration history) a developer-only option from this point on... :)

Comment: Don't fix what you can hide!

Comment: So what *should* I do to reopen a migrated question?

Comment: *cough* I'm again trying to reopen a migrated question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/whats-the-difference-between-hit-f5-and-ctrl-f5-in-browser). What is the procedure? I left it locked for now.