# Questions migrated from MSO do not have the migration notice on SO

Tags: feature-request, meta, migrated-questions

[In spite of the fact that Jeff was against the idea of migrating from MSO to SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78126/add-mso-so-migration-path) it would appear that it is now possible to do so [since this question was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93345/convert-android-code-to-monoandroid-code?noredirect=1).

However, the "migrated from" footer is not there.  To get the link that shows the question on MSO I had to hand-craft the URL with the `?noredirect=1` at the end of the question URL from the question list.

Can we add that footer?

To be clear, [this question on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78846/the-definition-of-c-based-language) was migrated from Stack Overflow and does have the proper footer there (which allows you to click back to the closed Stack Overflow version of the question)

**edit:** it appears this may have been a result of a diamond moderator migrating and then clearing the migration history, if this could be confirmed I would accept that as the answer

Comment: It occurs to me that the footer on a migration from MSO to SO, while promoting consistency, doesn't feel like it adds anything useful, other than to let everyone know that the OP was not observant enough to post the question in the correct place to begin with. This differs from the SO to MSO migration, which could simply be considered an honest, but off-topic, mistake.

Comment: Interesting take, though you could make similar arguments for all the migration paths.  Do other metas have this feature (maybe they have all along, I wouldn't know)?  If it's consistent within meta -> parent then that would make some sense.  Also, other than consistency it does also promote transparency as well - one can see the question as it was entered originally.  And it might be weird if a user who doesn't exist on SO somehow creates a question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diamond moderators have the ability to migrate a question to *any* site on the network.

They also have the ability to [clear migration history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58176/i-killed-a-question), which is what I suspect Bill did to that question on SO -- this would hide the footer that appears to be missing. From Jeff's answer in that question, it's unclear if he went through with what he said. (Note: I don't believe this moderator action shows up in the revision history which we non-diamonds see.)

Comment: If the migration history was cleared would that `noredirect=1` trick even work?  One would think it would re-parent the post to the new site and remove any vestiges on the old site.

Comment: @Daniel: No, clearing the migration history of the question on the target site would only affect it on the target site.

Comment: This looks like a classic case of clearing migration history. It does exactly everything that is seen here - it removes the footer and all traces of the migration from that post's revision history. [Here's an example of a migration from Meta to Stack Overflow that still has the footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900051/how-to-receive-an-sms-and-then-process-it-with-your-filtering-mechanism-to-transf). The only one who can confirm this, however, is the person who did the clearing or a dev - the diamond history does not include the act.

Comment: @Grace thanks, the fact that you found a counter-example is proof enough for me to dismiss this.  You can either update this answer or post your own and I'll accept that.