# Answering programming question on Meta

Tags: discussion, answers, meta, off-topic

I'm not sure if this has ever happened or not(I tried to search a lot on meta, but found no relevant questions regarding it). So here is my question. What happens if some user happens to post a programming question of Meta and another user answers that question on Meta itself.

Let's assume the OP of the question has described the problem very clearly with relevant examples and proper code snippets displaying the OP's efforts and also, the OP of the answer has posted the perfect answer the OP was in search of, with proper explanation, supported with facts, et al. What do we do in such a case?! Do we still downvote the question and close it, and let, what would have been a really nice question + answer combo, disappear in the woods somewhere? Or do we have a mechanism to protect(not sure what the exact word should be) the question along with its answer so that it can be useful for others in the future?

**Note:** I've not come across any such question myself, but just that this thought struck me suddenly(after seeing so many programming questions on meta these days).

Comment: I can imagine a migration in an _exceptional_ case like this

Comment: Close and delete, downvote if you must. They are off-topic here, and generally will not be migrated to SO.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely to happen though as those kinds of posts get closed very quickly on meta.

Comment: @all - But it could be a case, where it's a really good question right?! Are there any pre-conditions for a question to be be qualified as migratable, as such?

Comment: @R.J That's first of all very unlikely. And secondly, we're pretty fast at closing them to begin with. I'm all in favour of having the OP ask it again on SO. That's what they should have done in the first place.

Comment: @Bart - Agreed that it is very unlikely, but just because it's unlikely, we can't rule that out right? Also, we have evidence that a question can be migrated from [MSO to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5900051/2024761). Then why can't we do the same in such a situation?! Am just curious as to how that decision, to migrate or not to, is made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The kind of user that asks well-written and researched questions usually also manages to post on the correct site in the first place. I think I remember a single good question being posted on MSO, and lots of really bad ones.

In the case of a truly great question posted by accident here, it should probably be migrated. But in general we don't do that, and downvote and close is the corrct response.

Comment: But it could be a case, where it's a really good question right? Are there any pre-conditions for a question to satisfy a migration as such?

Comment: I have seen questions get migrated to meta if it deserves to be here, why the other way round not acceptable??

Comment: @CRUSADER let's just say the probability of the preconditions being satisfied is astronomically low

Comment: Come to think of it @mad, is it even possible to migrate from Meta to SO? Wasn't that impossible to begin with?

Comment: Does this look like a good programming question? I think it could live long and prosper on SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202798/1-single-letter-spacing

Comment: @Bart moderators can do anything if you ask them nicely

Comment: @JanDvorak Turns out it used to not be possible, but by now is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93347/questions-migrated-from-mso-do-not-have-the-migration-notice-on-so

Comment: @JanDvorak the question you linked to could be better. There is hardly any research seen, no explanation where his font came from and so on.

Answer (score 10):

Don't answer off-topic programming questions on Meta. Such questions do not migrated because we discourage that behavior. So answering those questions will encourage them to ask more. If I see someone answer programming question on Meta, I generally downvote it and ask the author to not answer programming questions on Meta via comments.

Additionally the user who ask such questions may have post ban on Stack Overflow. So by answering them we help them to overcome the postban without any efforts on main site itself.